# Machine learning (CNN) - What questions can I answer while violating assumption of independence?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, assumptions, nested-data, neuroimaging

**Introduction to the experiment and data type**:

Suppose that I have 20 or so participants exposed to visual stimuli in several trials in two different conditions: Simple, and Complex, of 3 flavors each. That is, there are 3 different versions of a Simple stimulus, and 3 different versions of a Complex stimulus that they are exposed to over multiple trials. FNIRS data was acquired while they viewed the stimuli - functional near infrared spectroscopy - and so we have time series data as our neuroimaging data.

We will convert these time series to images, and conduct image classification with a convolution neural network (CNN) to see whether it is possible for the CNN's - for the two conditions Simple and Complex respectively, so we get two separate networks here - to classify the 3 different classes in each condition with a sensible accuracy. This would be done on an individual level first - meaning I would feed **just one** participant's data for e.g. all his/her Simple trials into a CNN, get the performance score for the classification of the 3 classes, and do these steps separately for each of the 20 participants, ending up with loads of performance scores for respectively the Simple condition and the Complex condition, which I can average. The interesting bits here are how well the CNN's classify on average for Simple/Complex stimuli, as this says something about representation of knowledge in the brain if they are significantly different.

**My actual question relates to this:**

On top of this individual-level type of classification, I also was thinking to do a group level analysis. This would be done by pooling all participants' data together for respectively Simple and Complex stimuli (so we get two more CNN's, one for Simple and one for Complex, but this time **not per person, but with all trials in the condition, disregarding essentially that I have more people in the dataset**. After, the goal is to assess the classification ability of the CNNs on this kind of group-level.

The interesting thing with this idea is that, since my research question relates to individual differences in brain dynamics - when pooling all participants data (meaning, take all trials from all participants in the e.g. Simple condition and feed one CNN - and similarly, take all trials from all participants in the Complex condition and feed **another** CNN, so I end up with the two group-level-CNNs), **then** if the classification still is quite good e.g. in classifying the 3 different Complex stimuli across all participants, thereby violating the assumption of independence, this means that there are some brain dynamics that are common between all the people since the CNN obtained a sensible performance score, and that the 3 classes are eliciting significantly different brain dynamics across all people. This has great implications for BCI research.

***But - as said - it breaks the assumption of independence to pool the data like this. I am in doubts as to what effect this has on my possible conclusions - is this at all is a valid way to go to assess the general patterns in brain dynamics-question that this analysis would try to answer?*** ***Again, if the classification in the group-level CNN is good in terms of performance, that would mean there are general patterns across all these people - but can I ***say*** that, when I have broken the assumption of independence?***

I should of course account for the hierarchical data structure, but I feel the purpose of the question I am asking - whether the CNN is able to find general patterns in my data that is pooled - leads me to need to ignore it?

Any tips at all are gladly received and I am also open to redesign my analysis plan of course - and I am quite new to CNNs, so really, I am grateful for all tips and critique you have to give.